# Build success but application can’t install in device

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

**Version details:**
ionic version - “6.10.1”,
ionic-angular: “3.9.9”

**Issue description:**
Whenever run **ionic cordova run android** command on the project and it complete all the process and will show a build successful and generate an apk file on a respected path but after that getting error for installing on the device.

[image]

Comment: Hello! There's probably an issue with any of the cordova plugins... Could you add the output of the entire build process?

Comment: Hello,
@sebaferreras thank you so much for your response and the issue on the cordova plugin so It solved.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved the issue! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going to **Build -> Rebuild Project** first? It helped me with many issues.

Also try first **File -> Invalidate Caches** and then Rebuild.